# Error:(24, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android,i installed Android Studio **1.4.1** ,i am getting following errors.how may i resolve these error?

**Gradle Sync**

```
Error:(24, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:C:/Users/Admin/AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstApp/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

**Gradle Build**

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any matches for com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+ as no versions of com.android.support:appcompat-v7 are available.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
     Required by:
         MyFirstApp:app:unspecified
```

**Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.admin.myfirstapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
}
```

Comment: Can you include your build.gradle file?  It is most likely because you do not have the support library installed.

Comment: @TristanWiley added,please check

Comment: try with compileSDK version 21

Comment: Could you please check if you have appcompat-v7 library in `android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/20.+`. If you don't have it, downloading support repositories using SDK Manager might help.

Comment: ,where may i find this ? i have 64 bit system

Comment: Open SDK Manager in Android Studio and you'll be able to see the Android SDK Location. Navigate to that folder and you'll be able to find extras, tools and other folders.

Answer (score 2):

Are you behind a firewall? You might need to do this in the project build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    jcenter {
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
}
```

Comment: i added above lines to build.gradle file at the end but still showing same error

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE edition (is just like Android Studio) this is already set as default through jcenter().

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my problem was that the user running studio android did not have permissions to affect the root directory of android. In my case I gave permissions to that directory with the command:

```
chdown -R myuser /opt/android-studio/
```